# How can I remove the white under base?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

How can I remove the white under base from an object when opened in photoshop? I want to use this image for print and do not want a background to appear on the printed garment.

Comment: Now it the place to contact the printer and ask the proper Image format. If you print in CMYK, white means = no ink. Generally PNG isn't accepted for CMYK printing, because it doesn't support CMYK colors, but many print houses  and nearly all home and office printing machines have started to accept 24 bit PNGs and other RGB files because consumers and usual workers generally have no CMYK aware software. If you already have an order to make the background transparent, you should show your image at least as screenshot, because the working method depends on image content.

Comment: there are so many questions on GD.SE about background removal with Photoshop, not a single one of these solve your problem? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+%5Bphotoshop%5D+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ayes

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29545/18168)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove neutral background in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/how-to-remove-neutral-background-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to remove white background from an object in Photoshop:

1. Open an image in Photoshop. A number of “Palettes” shows to the right side of the screen.
2. Find Layered Palette.
3. Click on layer from the top of the menu options, Go to New > Layer from Background. Then New layer dialog box will appear.
4. Use Magic wand tool to select the pixels of a certain color within the image. For removing the white background, use magic wand tool to click an area of background and connected pixels of colors within the specified tolerance will be selected. Now press the delete button.
5. Clicking the mouse over the area of background which you want to remove.

In this way, the background will be removed in Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks for your effort answering the question. Check [answer] to learn more about it; essentially avoid answering questions that are not well formulated or have already been asked, you can [flag] it as duplicates instead.