# Made transparent background for a signature: tools gratis on line without sign in/registration

Tags: tools, resource-recommendations, image-format, scanning, free

We suppose that I put my signature on a piece of white paper with my first and last name on it. After I execute a scan of this signature in `.pdf`, or `.png` or `.tiff`, etc. (as file image).

What are the steps of a specific software to select only the signature, make the background transparent so that I can move it in a word document using only free tools on line without sign in or registration?

Comment: If you have access to Photoshop and a scan of the signature, this will give you good results and keep anti-aliasing intact: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29545/18168

Comment: @curious Is it possible to reopen, please, my question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to know the steps of a specific online tool or are you looking for an online tool?

Comment: @curious exact! Thank you to have understood my comment.

Comment: @curious I hope it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GIMP. Open your file. If it's not RGB, change the mode to RGB (=Image > Mode > RGB).

Insert alpha channel, if it does not already exist. Goto Layer > Transparency. Option "Add alpha channel" is grayed, if there's already one.

Increase the contrast with Color > Curves so that paper is full white. Adjust the hue and saturation of the writing good after the paper is white. Do it with Colors > Hue-Saturation. Be sure you do not make the background grey.

You should have a single layer image:

[image]

(the text here is random jumble scratched with the mouse, it's not readable writing in any language)

Then set the current foreground drawing color to white and apply Color > Color to alpha. White changes to transparency:

[image]

Then export your image as PNG. It may be a good idea at first check it has the right print size and resolution (300dpi). For it goto Image > Print Size.